# Struts2 href trigger an action with parameter

Tags: jsp, struts2

I have a link in JSP like this

```
<a href="<s:url action="aUrlAction" />">a variable</a>
```

The struts2 action code is

```
public SomeAction extends ActionSupport{
    private String aVariable;
    // aVariable getters and setters
    public execute(){
        doSomeThing(aVariable);  
    }
}
```

Strtus2 mapping is

```
<action name="aUrlAction" class="***.SomeAction">
    <result>....</result>
</action>
```

How can I pass in `aVariable` from clicking `<a>` tag. I want pass in the text between `<a></a>` to the action. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass parameter like this :

```
<s:url var="test" action="aUrlAction">
  <s:param name="aVariable">value</s:param>
</s:url>
<a href="${test}">Test</a>
```

Comment: Use `var` instead of `id`.

Comment: you can also use id as i have used in my project which is develop in struts2 and never face any problem.

Comment: You can until you can't. `id` is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks @Aleksandr M for information. i have change id to var. check is it correct?

Comment: @user2482616 The `url` tag is using `action` attribute to specify an action name.

Comment: i have changed value to action but value can also be used as i have used it in my project in which i am using struts 2.3.15 i am not having problem within.

Comment: hi, is there any way that we can pass a javascript variable as the value for the param?